# Compute the following norm derivatives

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I was wondering if anyone can explain me how to compute the derivatives of the following norms:

1. $\frac{d}{ds}||x+sp||^2_q$ for $x,p\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $1<q<\infty$
2. $\bigtriangledown ||u(x)||^2_2$ where $u: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ is sufficiently smooth, and
3. $\Delta||x||_2:=div(\bigtriangledown||x||_2):=\bigtriangledown \cdot (\bigtriangledown||x||_2)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything before asking the question?

Comment: Well, I tried using the definitions of the norms and then use some differentiation rules but it didn't seem to work out.

Comment: @madlin, write here your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is a composition of the next functions:
$$\mkern-1em j_p:\Bbb R\longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$$
$$s\longmapsto sp$$

$$\mkern-1em T_z:\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$$
$$v\longmapsto x+v$$

$$\mkern-1em N_q:\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow \Bbb R$$
$$v\longmapsto \|v\|_q$$

$$\mkern-1em S:\Bbb R\longrightarrow \Bbb R$$
$$t\longmapsto t^2$$

Compute the derivatives of each function and use the chain rule.